# Is it possible to download flickr app video in Iphone App ? If yes, then how?

Tags: ios, objective-c, flickr

I want to download flickr app video in my iOS App, but I cant find any link or source.

**Is it possible to access video of flickr app from Iphone app ?**

**If yes, then how ?**

**If no, then why ?**

If you know any link related it, Please tell me.

Comment: Did you try reading the [documentation](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/) for the flickr API? I think videos might be treated the same as photos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"photos AND videos are returned by any method which used to return just photos"

source: [Videos in the Flickr API](http://code.flickr.net/2008/05/01/videos-in-the-flickr-api/)

Comment: Did you read the link? If I understand correctly, you shouldn't have to change anything.